# Linux max. value for vm.max_map_count

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

I'm planning to increase significantly the default value of 65k max mappings; let's say multiply by 10. Assuming we have enough memory on the machine is there anything I should take care of doing that? E.g., any performance issue? Thx.

Comment: What are you doing which could possibly require this?

Comment: A process is memory mapping a lots of memory using 1MB buffers (each buffer being partially filled and used). The machine has a lots of RAM.

Comment: read this:
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683850/how-much-memory-could-vm-use-in-linux)